# accordition section closed at start JqueryUI

Tags: jquery

when i open a page with an accordition declared by this way

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordition1" ).accordion({collapsible: true});
  });
```

with four section, the first is ever opened.

how can i make the first section of the accordition being closed at start?

Regards, Rodolfo Rollo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jQueryUI accordion:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordition1" ).accordion({collapsible: true,active:false});
  });
```